# How can I alter the build number from jenkins by applying a system property?

Tags: git, maven, jenkins

I am trying to unify two CI profiles for a project with two branches. The `master` branch contains the production branch built once a night and a `dev` branch contains the development branch.

To automate the `-SNAPSHOT` suffix on the DEV branch I've applied the following POM.

```
<version>1.1.11${build.suffix}</version>
<properties>
    <build.suffix>-SNAPSHOT</build.suffix>
</properties>
```

Then I have two build configurations, the prod one has a `-Dbuild.suffix=".$BUILD_NUMBER"` assigned to `MAVEN_OPTS` in jenkins yet maven always seems to build without the suffix and always puts `-SNAPSHOT` at the end of each build.

Running locally it works fine, i.e.

```
mvn -Dbuild.suffix=".123" clean package
```

works fine.

I'm also getting the following warning, is there a better way of doing what I'm trying to do?

```
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.johnsands:unite:war:1.1.11-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'version' contains an expression but should be a constant. @ com.johnsands:unite:1.1.11${build.suffix}, /Users/bryan/Development/unite/pom.xml, line 11, column 12
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a [reason](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-users/201201.mbox/%3CCA+nPnMyb_W4Ldrg5zTn5NX3F2kcrPXDefS4gjzz3OE0cUy1rXw@mail.gmail.com%3E) why maven no longer allows expressions in `<version>` tag. Copy/pasting the relevant line...

> the pom that gets deployed will not have the property value resolved,
>   so anyone depending on that pom will pick up the dependency as being
>   the string uninterpolated with the ${ } and much hilarity will ensue
>   in your build process.

You could look at [maven versions plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/), specifically `mvn version:set` but this alters the `pom.xml` file and wouldn't make sense inside the CI environment.

Comment: okay, I can see and I can accept the reasoning for not using macros in version number. I would prefer avoiding the use of the versions plugin as you rightly mention it updates the pom which can be annoying for development, it's easier to just update the pom manually. I could simply script versions to update the pom, then a post build script to restore the pom from scm. I shall investigate.

Comment: Nup, just thought about it and versions isn't going to cut it. I was trying to prevent two things, accidentally leaving "-SNAPSHOT" in the prod branch and preventing a build failure when the version number had not been incremented causing maven to fail during "deploy", I forget the latter a little actually.

Comment: Thinking about it further, maybe I could leave "-SNAPSHOT" in the prod branch and do a replacement via versions:set, how can I get the current version number only from the cmd line that I could use to pass to set?

Answer (score 0):

Generally SNAPSHOT is for development branch (master, prod, dev etc). So leaving SNAPSHOT is prod branch is good. 
Better solution is versioning master/prod artefact with sample like XXX-FINAL-SNAPSHOT or dev branch with XXX-DEV-SNAPSHOT.

Released product from master/prod should have version -XXX, maven-release-plugin do this for you.

Comment: You may have misinterpreted my question. If you see my post you will see that I am trying to automate the -SNAPSHOT suffix without it residing in SCM. As noted in my question that I have two build profiles in Jenkins for prod and dev that attempt to set the suffix.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've done for those that need the help.

1. As per [Raghuram's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19584548/140037) I am using the [maven versions plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) to set the version.
2. My DEV branch always contains `-SNAPSHOT` text, prod branch is optional.
3. I use a pre-build script on PROD to extract the version, remove the `-SNAPSHOT` text and append `.$BUILD_NUMBER` to the version which is then set with [versions:set](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/set-mojo.html).
4. A post build script will then restore the original pom that the versions plugin backs up for us.

So putting it together.

**Pre-Build Script**: if anyone can tell me a cleaner way to get the version number I'd like to know:

```bash
ver=$(sed -n '/<version>/{p;q;}' pom.xml|grep '<version>'|sed 's/.*>\(.*\)<.*/\1/' | sed 's/-SNAPSHOT//').$BUILD_NUMBER
echo "Setting version to $ver"
mvn -DnewVersion="$ver" versions:set
```

**Post-Build Script**

```bash
test -f pom.xml.versionsBackup && mv pom.xml.versionsBackup pom.xml
```

The development cycle now ensures that the bugfix branches that are generally merged quickly will not require the version number int he pom to be updated, they can then safely be merged back into the prod branch.